# Get String based on multiple bit value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which I have multiple bit column like LH1,LH2,LH3,RH1, RH2,RH3. (This is example only and in original database I have more then 20 bit column.LH means Left Hand and RH means Right Hand. Same way I have Right Eye,Left Eye,Right Foot,Left Foot etc)

Please look at below image which display Data ,design and what will be output.

[image]

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE #LeftRight
(
    LH1 BIT,
    LH2 BIT,
    LH3 BIT,
    RH1 BIT,
    RH2 BIT,
    RH3 BIT
)

INSERT INTO #LeftRight
        ( LH1, LH2, LH3, RH1, RH2, RH3 )
VALUES  ( 1,1,0,1,1,0 ), (0,1,0,0,0,1), (1,0,1,1,0,1)

SELECT * 
FROM #LeftRight

DROP TABLE #LeftRight
```

Now based on those bit value I want to get a comma separated string.

I went through below link but it is not useful in my case

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112408/join-with-comma-separated-values-in-sql-server

Comment: i started looking at this but need to do something, so i've added the DDL in case someone else can use it.

Comment: Why are you not storing the bits in a single LH/RH column. It would make your life so much better than multiple bit fields. The solution below *works* but is going to be a *nightmare* with 20 columns.

Comment: Would you consider removing Allow Nulls? If there are no circumstances when a Null value is used it is easier to manage and write code for; perhaps default to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select replace('''' + iif([LH1]=1, '1, ','') + iif([LH2]=1, '2, ','') + iif([LH3]=1, '3, ','') + ''' AS LH, ', ', '' AS LH', ' '' AS LH') +
      replace('''' + iif([RH1]=1, '1, ','') + iif([RH2]=1, '2, ','') + iif([RH3]=1, '3, ','') + ''' AS RH, ', ', '' AS RH', ' '' AS RH')
from #LeftRight
```

Comment: Do you fancy writing this for the 20 LH/RH columns the OP suggests is the real case. I know I don't.

Comment: `IIF` is not available in SQL Server 2008. It was added in 2012.

Comment: @Jamiec I agree it was unwieldy. I've edited because REPLACE is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      LH1 BIT ,
      LH2 BIT ,
      LH3 BIT ,
      RH1 BIT ,
      RH2 BIT ,
      RH3 BIT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ),
        ( 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ),
        ( 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 )


SELECT  REPLACE(CONCAT('Row ', 
                       id, 
                       ': - ', 
                       '''', 
                       CASE WHEN LH1 = 1 THEN '1,' END,
                       CASE WHEN LH2 = 1 THEN '2,' END, 
                       CASE WHEN LH3 = 1 THEN '3,' END, 
                       ''' AS Lh, ''',
                       CASE WHEN RH1 = 1 THEN '1,' END,
                       CASE WHEN RH2 = 1 THEN '2,' END, 
                       CASE WHEN RH3 = 1 THEN '3,' END, 
                       ''' AS Rh'           
                       ), ',''' , '''')
FROM    @t t
```

Output:

```
Row 1: - '1,2' AS Lh, '1,2' AS Rh
Row 2: - '' AS Lh, '3' AS Rh
Row 3: - '1,3' AS Lh, '1,3' AS Rh
```

For older version use:

```
SELECT  REPLACE('Row ' + 
                CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
                ': - ''''' + 
                CASE WHEN LH1 = 1 THEN '1,' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN LH2 = 1 THEN '2,' ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN LH3 = 1 THEN '3,' ELSE '' END +
                ''' AS Lh, ''' +
                CASE WHEN RH1 = 1 THEN '1,' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN RH2 = 1 THEN '2,' ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN RH3 = 1 THEN '3,' ELSE '' END +
                ''' AS Rh', 
                ',''' , '''')
```

Comment: `CONCAT` was added in SQL Server 2012.